# name downloaded files after specific html element

Tags: html, download, mp3, extract, rename

In an nutshell:

I am looking for a way to automatically download files, listed as linkes on a website and give them meaningful names.

```
The situation:
```

There is a small radio show, I really love. It uploads FREE podcasts of there show. I recently found them and would like to download ALL of there shows (again they are free, so this is no copyright issue). Unfortunately on the website one can only download them one by one plus they .mp3s are given useless names.

The code of the side would look like this (maybe 1000 times...) .

```
Example: 
<a href="theWebsite.com/subSide/abc.mp3>The name of the mp3</a>
```

Is there a way to download them automatically or at least give them a meaningful name ("The name of the mp3.mp3" instead of "abc.mp3").

Could you recommend a tool or have an idea how I could approach this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just add the download attribute to the "a href tag". The string you assign to such attribute will be the name of the downloaded file. In your case, for example, you can do it like this:

```
<a href="theWebsite.com/subSide/abc.mp3 download="The name of the mp3">The name of the mp3</a>
```